# Merging denormalized data into a relational structure

Tags: java, merge, collections, denormalized

Let's say we have an entity `Foo` which comes from a denormalized DB table. And let's say it looks like this:

```
record Foo(int id, String discriminator, String value, String otherValue)
```

and we want to convert that to a relational structure which would look like this

```
Bar(
  String discriminator,
  List<Baz> bazList
)

Baz(
  String value,
  String otherValue
)
```

How could I elegantly accomplish something like that in java? The only thing that comes to mind is simply iterating over `Foo` convert and store the values in a map (so if a `Bar` instance already exists, add to it, if it doesn't create it). I am wondering if there is a way to do this without creating a map though

Comment: Is `bazList` grouped on `discriminator`?

Comment: Yeah. Each `discriminator` can have multliple `baz` instances. There can be 5 `Foo` entries with 3 having `TEST` as a `discriminator` value and that should be converted to one Bar instance with the `TEST` discriminator, containing 3 `Baz` instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need the intermediate map, but you can streamline it with streams:

```
List<Bar> result = foos.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(foo::discriminator,
                mapping(f -> new Baz(f.value(), f.otherValue()), toList())))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(e -> new Bar(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
        .toList();
```